How can I reduce the parasitic inductance of a metal film resistance
One example of a common resistor is metal film resistor, which has a high ESL. What are the practical steps to reduce ESL, other than to increase the area of the conductor and reducing the length of the conductor?

Change it out for a composition resistor? I don't get what you're asking here.

Why is the ESL a problem?

If you’re looking for high ESL then a wire wound is much worse unless it’s non-inductive wound. For small ESL you’d be using surface mount parts anyway, and there a metal film resistor is about as good as it gets. Can you explain why you care, what parts you have considered, whether they are through hole or surface mount, and what kind of answer you really need? Have you assembled an actual circuit? Can you show measurements for undue effects of  ESL? Please add these details to the question itself, then flag this comment as “no longer needed”. Do not reply in a comment please.

For thru hole components, inductance will probably be dominated by wire length.
Trimming MELF and metal film resistors is done by cutting the resistive film into a coil:

...so they do have a bit of inductance, which depends on how many turns the coil has, which depends on value. It's sometimes specified in the datasheet.
Chip resistors are also trimmed by laser cutting, using various patterns. Serpentine cut (M) will have more inductance, but still less than a coil.

Then there is the mounting inductance which depends on the area of the current loop. Mounting the resistor the usual way, with the resistive element on top, means this loop has more area. If the resistive element is on the bottom, the loop has less area so inductance is lower, but it sits closer to the board so capacitance to the ground plane will be higher. A while ago I needed a low inductance 1 ohm SMD resistor, so I simply took a normal resistor and soldered it upside down: the network analyzer confirmed the inductance was about half, it saved about 1nH. Here are some more "official" measurements:

Since chip resistors behave pretty much like a copper trace, a wider conductor means lower inductance, and longer means more inductanc. So "reverse geometry" resistors (or just a bunch of them in parallel) have lower inductance.
The impedance of an inductor is \$ 2j\pi Lf \$ so 1nH means 6 mOhms added impedance at 1Mhz. Thus inductance of SMD chip resistors may begin to matters at MHz frequency only if the resistor value is very low, like a current sense application in high speed switching converter. For higher values you'd need much higher frequency to worry about it.

Just a thought: The outer copper layers are usually 35 µm thick. And the L1-L2 dielectric is on the order of 100 µm for designs where you want low ESL. This means, that removing copper pads from right below the chip itself will bring the (downfacing) resistive film even closer to the return plane. The solder pad would then basically just be two bars beside the component, or maybe a U-shaped pad. If the solder paste aperture covers both the component pad and the PCB pad, this is even compatible with usual reflow. (admittedly a tricky edge case, but so is upside-down-mounting by itself ;) )

All R and C chips on PCB traces have inductance that depends mostly on the current loop area.
Yet each part contributes ESL on the log function of the length/width ratio.
Chips tend to have a 2D aspect ratio of 2:1 for L:W with a few exceptions like 805 case imperial, which is 2 mm long should be in the range of 0.5 to 1 nH, although Vijay advertises their 805 resistors being 0.5 to 5 nH so the construction details must matter as thickness also is also a variable to some extent. I’m not sure if they use laser cuts to trim precision shunts, but that would increase the path length a bit.
I recall a lab in Zurich who makes inductance meters reported that their 805 current shunt was 1.86 nH or 0.93 nH/mm and hopefully did not include the pads.
For current shunts to minimize the loop area the pair of traces should come out of one side between the pads to reduce leakage flux and inductance.
However for RF one must also consider the stray capacitance if over a ground plane, for which a signal trace is typically about 0.3 pF/mm.  The C depends on the mean Dk of the gap times the ratio of area/gap between conductors per unit length.
